# Turn SQL date red if it's not the current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, mysqli

I'm creating a simple PHP to do list. I want to turn the date red if it's not the current date. Here's part of my code, with the HTML removed:

```
<?php include "connection.php";?>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$task = isset($_POST['task']) ? $_POST['task'] : null;
$importance = isset($_POST['importance']) ? $_POST['importance'] : null;
$due_date = isset($_POST['due_date']) ? $_POST['due_date'] : null;
$order = isset($_POST['order']) ? $_POST['order'] : null;

if(isset($task,$importance,$due_date)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (task, importance, due_date) VALUES ('$task', '$importance', '$due_date')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if(!$result){
  die("Database query failed.");
}

}

}

if(isset($order)){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY {$order}";
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if(!$result){
  die("Database query failed.");
}

$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
if(isset($due_date)!=$current_date){
  $due_date_class="overdue";
} else {
  $due_date_class="not_overdue";
}

?>

<table>
<?php
while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $column["task"]?></td><td class="<?php echo $column["importance"] ?>"><?php echo $column["importance"]?></td><td class="<?php echo $due_date_class ?>"><?php echo $column["due_date"]?></td><td><?php echo "<a href='delete_one.php?id=".$column['id']."'>Delete</a>" ?></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>

<?php include "footer.php";?>
```

This is the part that isn't working. It's either turning all the rows red or black, depending on what date I enter:

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
    if(isset($due_date)!=$current_date){
      $due_date_class="overdue";
    } else {
      $due_date_class="not_overdue";
    }
```

Comment: what is `due_date` value ?

Comment: The due_date value depends on what you enter into the form, but it's in y-m-d format. So, the value for today would be 2017-10-03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
isset($due_date)
```

should be changed to

```
$due_date
```

Because, `isset` will return value `1` or `0`, which will be compared with date, which is going to be `false` all the time.

Instead, you could do following:

```
if(isset($due_date))
{
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
    if($due_date!=$current_date){
      $due_date_class="overdue";
    } else {
      $due_date_class="not_overdue";
    }
}
else
{
   echo "Not a valid Due Date";
}
```

**[>>>Demo<<<](https://ideone.com/UKkL6E)**

---

**Regarding variable scoping.**

You need to declare `$due_date_class` at very top, to increase its scope, otherwise you will get error. Since, scope of this variable will be limited to `if` and `else`.

Comment: I just tried that and my whole page broke and this error appeared: Notice: Undefined variable: due_date_class in C:\wamp\www\to_do_list\index.php on line 95.

Comment: Yes, it breaks my page.

Comment: @Julian That might be some other issue. For me, it works fine. Let me add demo link

Comment: @Julian It is clear from your error, it says `due_date_class` is undefined. That, means you have not defined `due_date_class`  variable and using it somewhere.

Comment: @Julian And, that means, my suggested code is working and you have something messed-up in your code. You need to check and correct accordingly.

Comment: Your suggestions fixed the error, but that wasn't my original question. My original question was "This is the part that isn't working. It's either turning all the rows red or black, depending on what date I enter:" This is still a problem. Instead of turning only the old dates red, every row in the table is turning red or black, depending on what I enter. If I enter the current date, it turns every row black, no matter what date the rows have. If I enter an old date, it turns every row red, no matter what date the rows have.

Comment: @Julian as per your question, you said, that part of the code is not working. right ? which I told you how to fix. Now, if it is getting completely red. Then, it has to do with logic, which you wrote.

Comment: @Julian I don't know, how you are changing the color, because I didn't see any code for color change. You need to post new question for this. And, explain logic and code for changing color

Comment: I'm trying to change the color of $column["due_date"] red, depending on whether the due_date_class is "overdue" or "not_overdue". "overdue" should turn the date red and "not_overdue" should turn the date black. I'm referring to this snippet:
`<tr><td><?php echo $column["task"]?></td><td class="<?php echo $column["importance"] ?>"><?php echo $column["importance"]?></td><td class="<?php echo $due_date_class ?>"><?php echo $column["due_date"]?></td><td><?php echo "<a href='delete_one.php?id=".$column['id']."'>Delete</a>" ?></td></tr>`

Comment: @Julian I understand, what you are trying. But, my question remain same, where is your color change code ? `html` won't himself change the color, you need to tell what color and what . right ? where is that, code ?

Comment: @Julian So, that is the reason, I was saying, you need to post a new question with showing the code for color change and only post the part of code where you are intend to change color, not complete page. Change the title of this question and close this post.

Comment: The color changes are in my CSS file:
`.overdue {
  color: red;
}

.not_overdue {
  color: black;
}
`